# Symfony2 bundle understanding

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I am new in Symfony2. I want to write for learning something like library (site will have part for users and secure part for admins with different designs and functionality). Should I create different bundles (like UserBundle or AdminBundle)? Or I should create one bundle. As in Zend Framework (I create 2 modules for user and admin). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're speaking of different designs and functionality, I assume the two parts won't really have much in common - at least from a front-end point of view. What will be shared essentially sums up to DB access, etc. - which is pretty much global stuff.

So yup, I'd go with two bundles, it'll be even more instructive to you IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. I think like you, but I wasn't sure :)

Comment: And if you ever need to access some Controller or anything from the other bundle, you still can as long as you use the namespaces properly. :)